# Password sent in plain text to server java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

I have a web application login form in spring security 3.1. The login form calls j_spring_security_check onsubmit and I have a custom auth manager that uses github rest api for authenticating login. The problem with this is, when the login information get logged on the server they are logged in plain text.

Posting my security-context.xml file

```html
<!-- Custom bean: Auth Manager -->
    <beans:bean id="customAuthmanager" class="com.RRCenter.securityMisc.AuthManager">
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Failed login bean -->
    <beans:bean id="failedLogin"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" p:defaultFailureUrl="/reuiweb/login?fail=true"></beans:bean>

    <!-- Successful login bean -->
    <beans:bean id="successLogin" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" p:defaultTargetUrl="/reuiweb/certifybundles?login=true"></beans:bean>

    <!-- <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </beans:bean> -->

    <!-- <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean> -->

    <!-- Actual auth manager -->
    <beans:bean id="customAuthFilter"  
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthmanager" 
        p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="failedLogin" 
        p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="successLogin"
        p:authenticationDetailsSource-ref="myAuthDetailsSource"
        ></beans:bean> 
        <!-- p:authenticationProvider-ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" -->

     <!-- Auth Details Bean -->
        <beans:bean id="myAuthDetailsSource" class="com.RRCenter.securityMisc.MyAuthDetailsSource"/>


    <!-- Successful login bean -->
    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        p:loginFormUrl="/reuiweb/login" />

    <security:authentication-manager />

    <!-- Test users -->


    <security:http auto-config="false" request-matcher="ant" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <!-- Enables the 9xxx ports -->
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
            <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
            <security:port-mapping http="9080" https="9443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>


    <security:http-basic authentication-details-source-ref="myAuthDetailsSource" />

        <!-- Session management -->

        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/reuiweb/login">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="99" expired-url="/reuiweb/login" />
        </security:session-management>


        <!-- Security schema -->
        ty:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" requires-channel="https"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/reuiweb/certifyProvider" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/reuiweb/allJobs" logout-url="/reuiweb/logout"/>  
        <security:custom-filter ref="customAuthFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>


    </security:http>
```

I read a couple of answers in stack overflow where it mentioned I had to use a user details service along with a password encoder bean

```html
<bean id="authProvider" 
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
  </bean>
```

However daoAuthentication provider is for cases where login password is stored in database. Could you let me know how to implement a userdetailsservice when authentication is provided by REST API services?

Comment: @holmis83  The server records each page it processed. When checking the logs for the page j_spring_security_check, the following information is getting logged------->

/reuiweb/j_spring_security_check?j_OTP=******(submitted form value)&submit=Submit&j_password={password in plain text}&j_username={submiited form value for username}

Comment: who puts this lines into log? your app? or server itself, like apache logs?

Comment: Then it seems to be problem with the login page. How does that look like?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov the server itself logs it. just like the apache logs! However, If we cud encode the password and pass it on to the server then  the server would log the encoded password right?

Comment: @holmis83 the login page is a form with 3 text boxes and a submit button which calls j_spring_security_check button as the form action

Comment: @noob-a-noob oh, you probably could use public-key encryption, with secret key know to server only. like RSA for example. encrypt password in browser, so log will contain only encrypted copy, and without access to your server code hacker will be unable to get original password. but I believe it's easier to properly configure server, apache httpd can disable logs for such things, for example

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Thank you for the suggestion. Changing the server settings and disabling logging worked. If could you put it up as an answer I  can upvote it.

Comment: it was stupid suggestion actually, see answer from @holmis83 :) I was confused by all details. Much better to use POST for such forms, as holmis83 suggests

Comment: @IgorArtamonov was/am using POST nevertheless it was logging. Tweaking with some internal server configurations helped

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` method for your login form:

```html
<form action="j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
  <!-- input fields etc -->
</form>
```

Then the values of the submitted fields will not appear in apache logs.